# how to nullify object values in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, null

Lets assume I have object such as;

```
var obj = {
    name: "alex",
    surname: "black",
    age: 21,
    grade: 14
}
```

I want to nullify all values as;

```
var obj = {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    age: 0, 
    grade: 0
}
```

How can I do this? I can look through keys by `Object.keys(obj)` and nullify each key according to their type.

Like;

```
var str ="";
for(var i =0; i < obj.length; i++){
   if(type of obj[i] === "string")
      str += Object.keys(obj)[i] + ': "",\n';
   if(type of obj[i] === "integer")
      str += Object.keys(obj)[i] + ': 0,\n';

}
```

Is it the proper way to do it?

edit: Thank you for your all answers. But this object can also contain objects. So I should loop through all the keys and nullify them as your example shows. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for..in` loop to iterate the object properties:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        obj[prop] = { string: '', number: 0 }[typeof obj[prop]];
    }
}
```

Alternatively maybe a `switch` inside the loop:

```
switch (typeof obj[prop]) {
    case 'string':
        obj[prop] = '';
        break;

    case 'number':
        obj[prop] = 0;
        break;

    default:
        obj[prop] = null;
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty slick solution. Let me ask how this `{ string: '', number: 0 }[typeof obj[prop]]` works? It seems as if the array literal following the object literal is acting like an `if/then` and a filter all at the same time. I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: It's nothing more than a shorthand of: `var o = { foo: 'bar' }; o['foo'];` Just instead if `'foo'`, we're using `typeof foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
    if(type of obj[key] === "string")
      // do something
    if(type of obj[key] === "integer")
      // do something

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like either of these:

[**for/in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (used to iterate ALL properties of an object) or

[**Object.keys(*obj*).forEach(*f*)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (gets array of an object's OWN properties and loops them)

```js
var obj = {
    name: "alex",
    surname: "black",
    age: 21,
    grade: 14,
    someObject: {dob: "12/16/66", address: "10 Main Street"}
}

var obj2 = {
    name: "alex",
    surname: "black",
    age: 21,
    grade: 14,
    someObject: {dob: "12/16/66", address: "10 Main Street"}
}

// Using for/in
function reset(obj){
  for(var k in obj){
   switch(typeof obj[k]){
       case "string":
          obj[k]="";
          break;
       case "number":
          obj[k]= 0;
          break;
       case "boolean":
          obj[k]= false;
          break;
       case "object":
          obj[k]= null;
          break;       
   }
  }
}

// Using Object.keys()
function reset2(obj){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
   switch(typeof obj2[k]){
       case "string":
          obj[k]="";
          break;
       case "number":
          obj[k]= 0;
          break;
       case "boolean":
          obj[k]= false;
          break;
       case "object":
          obj[k]= null;
          break;       
   }
  });
}

reset(obj);
console.log(obj);

reset2(obj2);
console.log(obj2);
```